# Are X and Y independent random variables?

Tags: probability, random-variables

> $\bullet$ Let $Z$ be uniformly distributed on $[-1,1]$.
>   $\bullet$ $X$ is a random variable such that $X=1$ when $Z>0$ and $X=-1$ otherwise.
>   $\bullet$ $Y$ is a random variable such that $Y=ZX$
>   Are $X$ and $Y$ independent??

From reading the question my first conclusion was that they are not independent but I am having difficulty finding a counterexample such that $$\mathbb{P}(A \cap B) \neq \mathbb{P}(A)\mathbb{P}(B)$$
Any help would be appreciated

Comment: I hope that you are looking for the correct probability with which you wish to compare $P(A)P(B)$ because $P(A\cup B)$ does not in general equal $P(A)P(B)$. Since $P(A), P(B) \leq 1$, $$P(A)P(B) \leq \min\{P(A), P(B)\}$$ while since $A, B \subset A\cup B$, $$P(A\cup B) \geq \max\{P(A), P(B)\}.$$

Comment: Apologies ! Latex error, I mean $\mathbb{P}(A \cap B) \neq \mathbb{P}(A)\mathbb{P}(B)$$

Comment: Note that if $Z\ge 0$, then $X=1$, and $Y=ZX=Z=|Z|$; while if $Z<0$, then $X=-1$, and $Y=ZX=-Z=|Z|$ again.  So the distribution of $Y$ can be expressed without referring to $X$: it's just uniform on $[0,1]$.

Comment: First conclusions are sometimes wrong, as we see here. But if you try to understand _why_ each attempted counterexample fails and look for a pattern, you may find a proof. (It works the other way, too: sometimes the flaw in an attempted proof reveals a counterexample.)

Answer (score 0):

Random variables $X : \Omega_X \rightarrow \mathbb R$ and $Y : \Omega_Y \rightarrow \mathbb R$ are independent random variables if events ${X \in [a,b]}$ and $Y \in [c,d]; \forall a,b,c,d \in \mathbb R$ are independent events. We can see that $Y$ equals $|Z|$, while $X = \frac{Z}{|Z|}$. Now try to understand whether $Y$ distribution is altered if we know the value of $X$. Let $X = -1$. Then $Z \in [-1,0]$ uniformly and $Y \in [0,1]$ uniformly. If $X = 1$, then $Z \in (0,1]$ uniformly and $Y \in (0,1]$ uniformly. Thus, we have the only value for $Y = 0$ which can't happen when $X = 1$. However, as this is one point, the measure of set containing such outcomes is $0$ and $P(Y=0|X=x) = 0$ regardless of distribution. Thus, $Y$ is uniformly distributed on $[0,1]$ independent from $X$ random variable.

Comment: Did you really mean to write, "if events ${X \in [a,b]}$ and $Y \in [c,d]; \forall a,b,c,d \in \mathbb R$"? Is part of the statement missing?

Comment: I'm sorry, that was a mistake, will correct in a minute.

Answer (score 0):

Consider two borelian $>0$ functions $f,g$.

$$
\begin{align}
E(f(X)g(Y)) &= 
\frac 12\left(\int _{-1}^0 f(-1) g(-x) dx + \int_0^1 f(1)g(x)dx\right)
\\&= 
\frac 12\left(\int _{0}^1 f(-1) g(x) dx + \int_0^1 f(1)g(x)dx\right)
\\&= 
\frac 12\left(f(-1) + f(1)\right)
\int _{0}^1 g(x)dx
\\&= 
\left[\frac 12\left( \int_{-1}^0 f(-1) dx + \int_0^1 f(1) dx \right)\right]
\left[\frac 12\left( \int _{-1}^0 g(-x) dx + \int_0^1 g(x) dx \right)\right]
\\&= E(f(X))\times E(g(Y))
\end{align}
$$

hence $X,Y $ are independant.